# How to implement an interface while doing local inheritance of existing class

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, overriding

I need to create an object from a bit modified class (e.g. From JButton). This modification consists of adding simple method and implementing additional interface, something like this:

```
public void randomMethod() {

    JButton button = new JButton() implements updatable{ 
     public void update() {} 
    };
}
```

Is it even possible? Is yes, how to implement it?

I don't want to create separate class for it, especially when I have bunch of them to modify and I don't use their objects frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this using anonymous inner classes, you need to modify your `Updatable` interface as follows :

```
interface Updatable<T> {
    public void update();
    public void setComponent(T t);
}
```

You can then easily create anonymous inner classes for different components.

**Updatable JButton**

```
Updatable<JButton> updatableButton = new Updatable<JButton>() {
        private JButton jButton;

        public void setComponent(JButton jButton) {
            this.jButton = jButton;
        }

        public void update() {
            jButton.setText("someText");
        }   
    };

    updatableButton.setComponent(new JButton());
    updatableButton.update();
```

**Updatable JLabel**

```
Updatable<JLabel> updatableJLabel = new Updatable<JLabel>() {
        private JLabel jLabel;

        public void setComponent(JLabel jButton) {
            this.jLabel = jButton;
        }

        public void update() {
            jLabel.setText("someText");
        }   
    };

    updatableJLabel.setComponent(new JLabel());
    updatableJLabel.update();
```

You no longer have to create a new class which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use an abstract class leaving the `update` to be implemented as an interface:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
public abstract class UpdateableJButton extends JButton implements Updateable {
    // ...
}
```

Updateable interface:

```
public interface Updateable {

    public void update();
}
```

And now you can use the abstract class where the `update` implementation is left out:

```
UpdateableJButton button = new UpdateableJButton() {
    @Override
    public void update() {
        // add specific implementation
    }
};
```

Comment: *I don't want to create separate class for it,*

Comment: I think he doesn't want to create a separate class for each, but one for all is O.K.

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: WHY don't you want to create a separate class? Separate classes are good. In fact, you already _are_ creating a class, albeit an anonymous, inner class.

Comment: @CKing the idea is that he didn't want to create a separate class for each button because there are going to be plenty of buttons. But in this case, you create only *one* parent class, and all the buttons are still just anonymous classes with the specific implementation.

Comment: @RealSkeptic My interpretation of the question is that the OP does not want to explicitly create a `.java` file that has a class that `extends` `JButton` and implements `Updatable`. This is apparent from the OP's attempt; `JButton button = new JButton() implements updatable{ `. It is clear that the OP wants a class that is a sublclass of `JButton` and implements `Updatable` but does not want to create a new `.java` file for it. Correct me if I am wrong but `JButton button = new JButton() implements updatable{` is asking *How do I create an anonymous instance that implements an interface?*

Comment: @CKing One doesn't need to create a separate `.java` file for this. It could be a package-level, static nested class, etc.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sure. But the OP seems (in my opinion) to want an anonymous inner class and not a class so that bit of the argument is still valid. See the title of the question *How to implement an interface while doing local inheritance of existing class*

Comment: Let's see what OP has to say.